# Why does numpy array slice assignment change shape of array?

Tags: numpy

If I have

```
a = np.empty((10,1))
b = np.arange(5).reshape(-1,1)
```

Why can't I make the following assignment:

```
a[0:5,0] = b
```

I thought that a[0:5,0] would have the same shape as b, namely shape=(5,1). But it does not, instead we have a[0:5,0].shape = (5,) so I can't make that assignment and must do it this way

a[0:5,0] = b.reshape(5,)

Why does a[0:5,0] 'reshape' a?

Comment: Indexing by a scalar reduces the dimension.  That's a basic detail of `numpy` indexing.  And consistent with Python list indexing (indexing a list removes one layer of list nesting).

Comment: Sooner or later you'll want to read and understand https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing.  Or at least, keep that page handy for reference.  Or perhaps use https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating

Comment: And to test your understanding, why does `a[0:5,0] = b.T` work.  In other words, why can a (1,5) be assigned to a (5,) slot, but a (5,1) can't?  A (5,) can be assigned to a (1,5) slot, but not to a (5,1) slot.  You may need to read up on broadcasting.

Comment: @hpaulj, I see now that indexing by a scalar reduces the dimension, but it is not obvious from Python documentation that it does so.  If I did a[0:5,0:1] = b, it would work, even though it is essentially the same assignment.  Coming from a matlab background, this is surprising and not obvious, I think, from Python documentation.

Comment: In MATLAB everything is (at least] 2d. numpy 0,1,2,etc dims, and scalars. `a[0,0]` is a scalar, not a (1,1) array. The shapes (n,), (1,n], and (n,1) can also be confusing.